# Delegated Administration log in not working

Tags: administration, security, grant-login-access

I am using delegated administration to allow supervisors to log in as their subordinates. However it is not working.

I have set the correct users to give administrative access to and have set the role and assignable profiles. I have also checked the 'Enable Group for Login Access'.
[image]

I have also given the administrators 'Modify All Data' access.

I am testing by logging into the supervisors profile and navigating to a subordinate in Setup->Users. I do not see a login button on the subordinate.

Comment: My last comment was incorrect, so sorry, but i have another question, Are there restrictions on the access to login-as in your setup?  Did you try logging in as the subordinate and granting admin access to the supervisor?